# How do I get rid of unwanted motion blur?

Tags: motion-blur

I've got a fairly old (December 2007) photo of a train, which looks quite blurry because it ran too fast for the shutter speed (1/125") of my Olympus E-400 (@ ISO 320 & f/7.1):

[image]

I can't retry this shoot as the rolling stock depicted here is no longer in operation. What I could try (at least in theory), is to shrink the affected parts of the pic vertically by, say, 10%, but then I'd have issues with missing parts of the background.

Is there a possibility to "save" this picture?

**UPDATE:** Here is [the pic in original size, just converted to JPEG.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oiT5rr8bGgLQTC689)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can slightly blurred photos be improved in post processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/how-can-slightly-blurred-photos-be-improved-in-post-processing)

Comment: Also related: [Can anyone recommend *freeware* to reduce motion blur by deconvolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9617/15871) and [How can I fix an out of focus photo? Is there an app for that? I don't have Photoshop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92194/15871) and [In an image with camera shake and a point light source, can the shape of the point light source be used to practically reduce the shake significantly?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105455/15871)

Comment: You might also want to look at [Focus problem vs. motion blur vs. camera shake - how to tell the difference?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8348/15871) as the stationary objects in your image are also blurred. Not all of the blur in the image was due to the motion of the train.

Comment: Well, it's rather not camera shake at 1/125", but my old Olympus did have autofocus issues under poor lighting conditions. I have already used USM to get rid of it, but there's still the motion blur left.

Comment: It's certainly possible to have demonstrable camera shake at 1/125, particularly with narrow angles of view.

Comment: Is that the original, or do you have a better/larger copy of it? It looks slightly better after running it through Topaz Sharpen, however, if I zoom in, I'm not sure it's an improvement, lots of minor artifacts. Might be better if you have a higher resolution copy though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is a downsampled copy. The original would have been too large, but I can upload it into a cloud if you wish.

Comment: @Neppomuk Please do, I will run Topaz Sharpen on it and give you back link to it. No guarantees it will improve the qualitythough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a lengthy search and a bit of trial and error, an AI-based solution named [Baseten GFP-GAN](https://app.baseten.co/apps/QPp4nPE/operator_views/RqgOnqV) turned out to be quite good at resharpening blurry photos. However, details like logos or texts looked somehow uneven afterwards or had not been sharpened at all:

[image: Sharpened by using Baseten GFP-GAN. Texts uneven, number & logo still blurry.]

So I had no alternative than to take the number and logo from some other (sharp) photo, paste them and adjust their colors. It still doesn't look perfect, [but good enough for me:](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wiener_Linien_E6_4905_Linie_U6_Gumpendorfer_Stra%C3%9Fe_(2007).jpg)

[image: Sharpened by using Baseten GFP-GAN, number & logo taken from another pic.]

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I tried it on Topaz products PhotoAI and SharpenAI - graphics always get mangled up though - https://i.imgur.com/lsohIY7.jpg topaz (selected region standard/lens/motion/v4), https://i.imgur.com/UZPjaPm.jpg pc240120-SharpenAI-Motion, https://i.imgur.com/yuZ8wvw.jpg pc240120-SharpenAI-Standard (v2) - in all cases, the default settings were too strong, really messing up the text; really low, subtle, values went some way to preserve them to some degree, and did region selecting as well.

Comment: No, I don't mind: SharpenAI-Motion is even quite good (save for the fact that text is mangled up). What's really poor, is SharpenAI-Standard (v2). Baseten isn't bad either, but it also has its issues with text and vibration blur + motion blur as in the front of the train.

Comment: Yes, that is the limitation of this kind of software for now. It is okay, not great, but not the worst... (when it works. With no changes, one of the programs refuses to load at all today.. so inconsistent)