# How best to remove directional motion-blur from photos (on Linux)?

Tags: software, linux, motion-blur

I took some photos of the moon last night.  I wanted good color without a lot of noise, so used ISO 100 and a long exposure (10 seconds with a 400mm lens).  I have a good tripod and head and used a 2 second shutter delay so that I wasn't touching the camera.  This has worked great for me for terrestrial shots in the past, but the earth turns enough in 10 seconds to give the shot a very directional blur.  Oops!

I'm familiar with Sharpen, Unsharp Mask, and similar filters.  I'm specifically wondering how to sharpen only in one direction.  Like a sharpen filter where I specify an angle and a length.  I know the earth makes an arc, not a line, but a line would be close enough to fix this.

Also, I run Ubuntu 18.04 Linux.  I normally use Darktable and Gimp, but can try other things or an online service.  It does not have to be free.  I just can't use Windows-only or Mac-only software.

Comment: Related: [Can anyone recommend *freeware* to reduce motion blur by deconvolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9617/15871) and [What plugin for Photoshop can I use to remove camera-shake blur?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11348/15871) and [How can I fix the blur in this photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89070/15871) and [How can I fix an out of focus photo? Is there an app for that? I don't have Photoshop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92194/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC Wiener Filter might be the answer I'm looking for.  Thanks!